# Ant build.xml requires user input, but Eclipse can't open SWT widget

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have an Antbuild script that I run from the Eclipse plugin that does the following:

```
<echo message="About to request user input in popup dialog box..." />
<input message="Please enter the production version number.This will determine where the JAR file is published.${line.separator}${line.separator}(For example, if you enter 1.2.3.4 the JAR will be published to [${deploy.prod.path.prefix}1.2.3.4${deploy.prod.path.postfix}])${line.separator}" addproperty="deploy.prod.version"/>
<echo message="You entered version ${deploy.prod.version}" />
```

What this used to do is open an Eclipse dialog box like the following (which implicitly uses SWT, I don't explicitly use SWT myself):

[image]

But now that I've upgraded to Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 the input call fails with the following:

```
[echo] About to request user input in popup dialog box...

BUILD FAILED
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Listener
```

I thought SWT was an integral part of Eclipse so there's no need to install that separately - anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't shown us where you are using SWT.

Comment: I don't use SWT myself - Eclipse uses it under the hood to display a dialog. I've attached a screenshot of what it used to look like before it broke on the upgrade.

Comment: Did you finally find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, changed the build process to circumvent.